# Wordpress file permissions/group ownership

Tags: linux, wordpress, permissions, file-permissions

I recently helped the company "BBB" with their WordPress site (on shared hosting).  It used to work, but recently whenever they would try to update a plugins or WordPress, they got an error:

`Update Failed:  Could not copy file.`

This was resolved by recursively setting the file ownership and permissions (some belonged to the group "bbb", others belonging to "apache" - they were all changed to "bbb").

My question is: how did some of the WordPress files/folders get set to belong to apache in the first place, so it can be prevented from happening again?

Comment: That's almost impossible for us to answer.. Ask the hosting company.. What control panel do they use? If the shared server is set up correctly the you shouldn't have control to switch your own files ownership (otherwise what would prevent someone else on the server taking ownership of your files).. My guess is a server admin wasn't being careful and did that as root (or at least through sudo)..

Comment: Not all of the files/folders had changed permission/group -- only some.  What I am asking is, could a WordPress plugin (or WordPress itself) have changed it?  Or must it have been a server admin?

Comment: Hi Alan, again its difficult to say. I would assume that if the server is set up correctly you won't have permissions to change ownership. So without any additional info I'd say that either an admin changed it, or the server is not well set up. You could always try SSHing in and make sure that you're SSHed as the same user that the web files run as. Then try chowing a file to see...